# Exception has occurred: ImportError cannot import name '_typeconv' while using librosa

Tags: python-3.x, librosa

this is a python script to find the pitch of the give .wav file using librosa, as i run the program the import error mentioned in the title occurs. can anybody help me?

```
import librosa
import numpy as np

filename = "m1.wav"
y, sr = librosa.load(filename, sr=44.1)
pitches, magnitudes = librosa.core.piptrack(y=y, sr=sr, fmin=75, fmax=1600)
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
print(pitches[np.nonzero(pitches)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your error is related with the installation of "numba" package. Can you try upgrading it with pip?